# How to upload a png file in cocos2dx to a php server

Tags: php, upload, server, png, cocos2d-x-3.x

I need to upload a .png file from cocos2dx to a php server. (.txt is fine for testing purposes)

I edited the engine like described here:

http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/upload-file-with-httpclient-solved/18028/4
and here:
https://github.com/FenneX/FenneX/commit/134e9433c1dbc3ca6f772ce4c149bf911275a7e9

So now what? How can I upload a file to the server?

This is my attempt but I'm an http/network noob so I have no idea what I am doing... I just need a simple working example to start with.

cocos2dx upload button source:

```
    //  HTTP post
    auto buttonPost = CustomButton::create("Post data",[this](Ref *pSender){

        __String *dataToSend = __String::create("dataOne=45&dataTwo=100");


        cocos2d::network::HttpRequest *request =
            new cocos2d::network::HttpRequest();

        request->setUrl("http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/post.php");
        request->setRequestType(cocos2d::network::HttpRequest::Type::POSTFILE);

        request->setRequestData(dataToSend->getCString(), dataToSend->length());

        request->setFilePath("res/test.txt");

        request->setResponseCallback( [=]
            (network::HttpClient* client,
            network::HttpResponse* response)
        {

            std::vector<char> *buffer = response->getResponseData();
            printf("Get data from server");

            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < buffer->size(); i++)
            {
                printf("%c", (*buffer)[i]);
            }

            printf("\n\n\n");

            printf("Response Code %li   ", response->getResponseCode());

            if (200 == response->getResponseCode())
            {
                printf("OK \n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("failed \n");
            }

        });

        cocos2d::network::HttpClient::getInstance()->send(request);
        request->release();

    });
```

Php server side code:

```
        <?php
        $uploaddir = "uploads/";
        $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']);

        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile))
        {
          echo "The file has been uploaded successfully";
        }
        else
        {
          echo "There was an error uploading the file";
        }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks stack overflow for this 'great answer'...

The client code:

```
        //The url where you have the server side upload script
        std::string url = "http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/upload.php";


        //The basename is the whatever you use in the server side as 'file' id
        //I think can be 'uploadedfile'
        //or whatever as long as it'll be the same in both sides (client/server)
        //in php:
        //$_FILES['file']['name']
        //$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']

        std::string basename = "mobileFile";

        //File name and full path
        std::string filename = "chart.png";
        std::string path = "res/" + filename;

        long bufferSize = 0;
        unsigned char* pBuffer = CCFileUtils::getInstance()->getFileData(path.c_str(), "r", &bufferSize);

        //The same file stored as a string of "bytes" (it may contain zeroes)
        std::string data = std::string((const char*)pBuffer, bufferSize);


        //Create an http post request
        cocos2d::network::HttpRequest *request = new cocos2d::network::HttpRequest();
        request->setUrl(url.c_str());
        request->setRequestType(cocos2d::network::HttpRequest::Type::POST);

        //Include this boundary in the header and in the body of the request
        std::string boundary = "---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";

        //The content of the request must be multipart/form-data
        std::vector<std::string> contentType;
        contentType.push_back("Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);

        //Set the header with the previous content type
        request->setHeaders(contentType);

        //Build the body of the request. Include the boundary, basename and file name.
        //Specify the content disposition and type

        std::string body = "\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n";
        body = body + "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + basename
                    + "\"; filename=\"" + filename + "\"\r\n";
        body = body + "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n";

        //Then append the file data and again the boundary
        body = body + data;
        body = body + "\r\n--" + boundary + "--\r\n";

        request->setRequestData(body.data(), body.size());

        //Just a tag...
        request->setTag("UPLOAD FILE");

        //Check that everything went OK when the request response calls your app back:
            request->setResponseCallback( [=]
                (network::HttpClient* client,
                network::HttpResponse* response)
            {

                std::vector<char> *buffer = response->getResponseData();
                printf("Get data from server:\n");

                for (unsigned int i = 0; i < buffer->size(); i++)
                    { printf("%c", (*buffer)[i]); }

                printf(" Response Code %li   ", response->getResponseCode());
                if (200 == response->getResponseCode()){ printf("OK \n"); }
                else{ printf("failed \n"); }

            });

        //Finally send the request:
        cocos2d::network::HttpClient::getInstance()->send(request);

        //And then get rid of it:
        request->release();
```

The php code: (of course this is for testing purposes)

```
    <?php

        $base = 'mobileFile';
        $uploaddir = 'uploads/';
        $file = basename($_FILES[$base]['name']);
        $uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file;

        echo "file=".$file; 

        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$base]['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) 
        {
            echo "   uploaded: ".$file;
        }
        else 
        {
            echo "error";
        }

    ?>
```